# What is the OpenCV equivalent of Imagemagick's `+distort DePolar`

Tags: opencv, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

Imagemagick's `+distort DePolar` [documentation](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/#depolar) says that the command converts the image from polar to cartesian and preserves the aspect ratio of the polar image.

Is there an equivalent to this in OpenCV? I've been looking at [`linearPolar`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.1/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#gaa38a6884ac8b6e0b9bed47939b5362f3), but the function seems more complicated.

**EDIT:** `linearPolar` is close to `+distort DePolar`, but the Imagemagick command correctly changes the size of the resulting image, whereas `linearPolar` doesn't change the dimensions.

Comment: Would you mind to post an input and output sample? Also, do you prefer [tag:python] or [tag:c++]?

Answer (score 1):

`warpPolar` is the correct function to use since it allows specifying `dsize`, unlike `linearPolar`.

Here's the code that produces basically the same result as the Imagemagick command:

```py
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

def undistort(img):
    height, width, *_ = img.shape
    assert height == width, "we want a square image"
    radius = int(height / 2)
    image_center = radius, radius

    dest_width = int(np.ceil(np.pi * radius))
    dest_height = int(np.ceil(radius))
    dest_size = (dest_height, dest_width)

    undistorted_img = cv.warpPolar(src=img, dsize=dest_size, center=image_center, maxRadius=radius, flags=0)
    return cv.rotate(undistorted_img, cv.ROTATE_90_CLOCKWISE)
```